# Wordpress wp_enqueue loading css but not js

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

my website is loading the css file but not the js.
my header.php :

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="de-DE">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>//</title>   
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

and my functions.php :

```
<?php

    function include_all() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/app.css',false,'1.1','all');
        //---
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', array(), null, true);
        //---
        wp_enqueue_script( 'app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array('jquery'), null, true );


    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_all');

?>
```

i want to disable wordpress' jquery to use my own version, but its only loading the css. is this the best the way to include js&css in wordpress ?

Thanks in advance, i appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

please register js file & then enqueue it, try this example.

```
function include_all() {

 wp_register_script('app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
 wp_enqueue_script('app');
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_all');
```

Comment: check the enqueue parameters, wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); and define correctly in wp_register_script('app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js');
wp_enqueue_script('app');

Answer (score 0):

'jquery' name is already reserved. Use this one

```
wp_enqueue_script('custom-jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', array(), null, true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array('custom-jquery'), null, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

alright, its working now :D forgot to add `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in index.php

wp_enqueue_script( 'app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array('custom-jquery'), null, **true** );